# Heroku wont use Ruby version set in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile

I am trying to host Canvas LMS on Heroku for an app that I am developing, and I am running into issues deploying it.

Canvas LMS uses Ruby 2.1.6, and that isn't the default Ruby on Heroku. I went into the Gemfile, added this line `ruby "2.1.6"`, and when I deploy it to Heroku I get this error:

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing Ruby Ruby-2.3-support-is-untested-ruby-2.3.1
remote:  !     For supported Ruby versions see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14
remote:  !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/Ruby-2.3-support-is-untested-ruby-2.3.1.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I have no experience with Ruby so I really don't know how to tinker around and solve the issue. Everywhere I've looked said to just add the `ruby "2.1.6"` line to my Gemfile but that has not solved the issue.

Comment: Change `ruby "2.1.6"` to `ruby "2.1.10"` as that is the most recent version of `2.1` which is the only version supported on Cedar-14.

Comment: @EliSadoff will try that now, each push takes a long time so I'll get back once it finishes

Comment: @EliSadoff Still get the same error :(